# Combining 2 select statements in the same query on one column

Tags: sql

I'm trying to combine 2 sql result sets into 1.  I cannot have them in 1 select as performance is a huge issue.  So what I'd like to do is run both of them and combine the results on a primary key - all in one query.

For example.

```
select a,b,c,d from tablea;
select d,e,f,g from tableb;
```

How do I combine the results in the query itself.  Again the selects need to be seperate.

Output:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the two tables?

Comment: They both share column D.

Comment: "I'm trying to combine 2 sql result sets into 1. I cannot have them in 1 select as performance is a huge issue."  How do you expect to get one result set with more than one select?

Comment: So joining on column `D` is too much of a performance problem?

Comment: Having one encompassing select statement is fine....but these 2 need to be separate is what I meant,

Comment: Basically I tried a join...however what my second select does is run an average on several rows and returns a number for that key.  It is very taxing when I join on that table.

Comment: Well that changes the situation - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just join on column `D`:

```
select a, b, c, A.d, e, f, g 
from tablea A
INNER JOIN tableb B
  ON A.d = B.d
```

You *could* use subqueries:

```
SELECT a, b, c, A.d, e, f, g 
FROM
    (select a,b,c,d from tablea) A
INNER JOIN
    (select d,e,f,g from tableb) B
  ON A.d = B.d
```

or CTEs (which is a different way to use subqueries):

```
WITH A AS
(
    select a,b,c,d from tablea;
),
B AS 
(
    select d,e,f,g from tableb;
)
SELECT a, b, c, A.d, e, f, g 
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
  ON A.d = B.d
```

> what my second select does is run an average on several rows and returns a number for that key. It is very taxing when I join on that table.

OK That changes the situation.  A subquery or CTE is probably going to be your best bet.

Comment: and create indexes in both tables on column D to greatly boost performance.

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to run these select statments seperately? And then combining them.

Comment: @DStanley Your second solution is exactly what I needed.  Thank you!